# Dynamic group/transpose

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data on calls made to customers and need to transpose it (or at least group it properly) so it goes from this format to the next:

Have:

| ID | Dept | Call_no |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 |
| 1 | B | 2 |
| 2 | C | 1 |
| 3 | B | 1 |
| 3 | B | 2 |

Want:

| ID | Dept_1 | Dept_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B |
| 2 | C |  |
| 3 | B | B |

The call number is always 1 or 2. There are an undefined number of IDs (in the thousands and it changes daily) so it needs to be dynamic.

I've been looking at `PIVOT`, but I'm not sure it really does what I need. I remember doing something similar in Enterprise Guide using `GROUP BY` functions, but I can't figure out how I did it.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: This is called condiional aggregation. `SELECT ID, MAX(CASE WHEN call_no = 1 THEN Dept END) AS Dept1, MAX(CASE WHEN call_no = 2 THEN Dept END) AS Dept2 FROM yourtable GROUP BY ID`

Comment: @siggemannen Thank you, very helpful! Why do you do MAX() around the CASE WHEN statement?

Comment: Otherwise you won't be able to "collapse" several rows into a single one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would approach this as follows.

The IsNull can be removed if you are OK with NULLs where the `Call_No` is not applicable.

The aggregation can use min or max it doesn't matter, either chooses the non-null value.

```
select Id, 
    IsNull(min(case when Call_No = 1 then Dept end), '') Dept_1,
    IsNull(min(case when Call_No = 2 then Dept end), '') Dept_2
from t
group by Id;
```

Comment: Thank you, very helpful! Why do you do MIN() around the CASE WHEN statement?

Comment: Because this needs to aggregate and collapse NULL rows into a single row, this is the aggregation part of *conditional aggregation*, the conditional part being the *case expression*. Try it with and without to compare and you should understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

-- Get distinct call numbers to pivot
SELECT @cols = STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME('Dept_' + CAST(Call_no AS NVARCHAR(10))), ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 'Dept_' + CAST(Call_no AS NVARCHAR(10)))
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Call_no FROM YourTable) AS Departments

SET @query = '
SELECT ID, ' + @cols + '
FROM (
    SELECT ID, ''Dept_'' + CAST(Call_no AS NVARCHAR(10)) AS CallDept, Dept
    FROM YourTable
) src
PIVOT (
    MAX(Dept)
    FOR CallDept IN (' + @cols + ')
) piv
ORDER BY ID;';

EXECUTE(@query);
```

The above query will dynamically generate the columns `Dept_1`, `Dept_2`, and so on, based on the distinct `Call_no` values present in your your table. The `PIVOT` function aggregates the Dept values based on these dynamically generated column names. [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/cbDxqR37)

Answer (score 0):

If you want Pivot then below query will help:

```
SELECT  ID,  isnull([1],'') as 'Dept_1', isnull([2],'') as 'Dept_2'
FROM  
(
  SELECT ID, Dept, Call_no   
  FROM tbl_Dept
) AS SourceTable  
PIVOT  
(  
  max(Dept)  
  FOR Call_no IN ([1], [2])  
) AS PivotTable;
```